# android studio 0.5.2: could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

creation of projects fail in android studio 0.5.2.I have installed gradle 1.11

```
 Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApplication5'.
    > 

Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.

   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+.
     Required by:
         :MyApplication5:unspecified
      > org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

I have tried so many things that I have found on stack exchange. 
Reinstall android studio. invalidate caches, remove .gradle folder, restart android studio and rebuild my project. Change the version to 11 in the distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip. Used local gradle distribution instead of default gradle wrapper in the gradle settings.I always get this same failed message.

gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip
```

the gradle.build file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE 1

If I build with  --debug I get the following output:

```
 * Exception is:
20:54:34.245 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApplication6'.
20:54:34.246 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
20:54:34.249 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:57)
20:54:34.251 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:507)
20:54:34.252 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:82)
20:54:34.253 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:31)
20:54:34.255 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
20:54:34.257 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
20:54:34.258 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
20:54:34.259 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
20:54:34.260 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
20:54:34.261 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
20:54:34.262 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
20:54:34.264 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
20:54:34.265 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
20:54:34.267 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
20:54:34.268 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
20:54:34.269 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
20:54:34.270 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
20:54:34.271 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
20:54:34.272 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
20:54:34.273 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
20:54:34.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
20:54:34.275 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
20:54:34.276 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
20:54:34.288 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
20:54:34.290 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
20:54:34.291 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
20:54:34.292 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
20:54:34.293 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:52)
20:54:34.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:36)
20:54:34.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:106)
20:54:34.296 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:176)
20:54:34.298 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:465)
20:54:34.299 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:202)
20:54:34.301 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
20:54:34.302 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.updateClassPath(DefaultScriptHandler.java:75)
20:54:34.303 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:167)
20:54:34.304 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
20:54:34.305 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
20:54:34.307 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
20:54:34.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
20:54:34.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 25 more
20:54:34.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+.
20:54:34.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Required by:
20:54:34.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     :MyApplication6:unspecified
20:54:34.314 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain.resolve(UserResolverChain.java:67)
20:54:34.315 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:34)
20:54:34.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.projectmodule.ProjectDependencyResolver.resolve(ProjectDependencyResolver.java:48)
20:54:34.317 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LazyDependencyToModuleResolver$AbstractVersionResolveResult.resolve(LazyDependencyToModuleResolver.java:86)
20:54:34.319 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LazyDependencyToModuleResolver.resolve(LazyDependencyToModuleResolver.java:47)
20:54:34.320 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.VersionForcingDependencyToModuleResolver.resolve(VersionForcingDependencyToModuleResolver.java:48)
20:54:34.321 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionSelectorResolveState.resolveModuleRevisionId(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:936)
20:54:34.322 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.resolveModuleRevisionId(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:297)
20:54:34.338 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:94)
20:54:34.340 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:67)
20:54:34.341 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver$1.transform(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:108)
20:54:34.344 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver$1.transform(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:77)
20:54:34.346 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
20:54:34.347 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:77)
20:54:34.348 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.create(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:39)
20:54:34.350 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.create(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:37)
20:54:34.351 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:187)
20:54:34.353 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:102)
20:54:34.354 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:189)
20:54:34.355 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:61)
20:54:34.356 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:37)
20:54:34.357 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:41)
20:54:34.358 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.java:51)
20:54:34.360 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:44)
20:54:34.361 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolve(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:42)
20:54:34.362 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
20:54:34.363 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:230)
20:54:34.364 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
20:54:34.365 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:463)
20:54:34.367 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 33 more
20:54:34.368 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
20:54:34.369 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
20:54:34.370 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:186)
20:54:34.371 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
20:54:34.372 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
20:54:34.373 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
20:54:34.374 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:118)
20:54:34.375 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:111)
20:54:34.376 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:87)
20:54:34.377 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:78)
20:54:34.378 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:66)
20:54:34.379 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:70)
20:54:34.395 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.getResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:46)
20:54:34.397 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.getResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:32)
20:54:34.398 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.DefaultExternalResourceRepository.getResource(DefaultExternalResourceRepository.java:61)
20:54:34.401 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenMetadataLoader.parseMavenMetadataInfo(MavenMetadataLoader.java:56)
20:54:34.405 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenMetadataLoader.load(MavenMetadataLoader.java:46)
20:54:34.409 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenVersionLister$1.visit(MavenVersionLister.java:44)
20:54:34.412 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ChainedVersionLister$1.visit(ChainedVersionLister.java:49)
20:54:34.413 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.listVersionsForAllPatterns(ExternalResourceResolver.java:322)
20:54:34.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.findDynamicDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:185)
20:54:34.415 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.getDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:163)
20:54:34.417 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.getDependency(MavenResolver.java:81)
20:54:34.418 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.getDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:157)
20:54:34.419 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository$1.run(CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository.java:46)
20:54:34.420 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
20:54:34.421 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:237)
20:54:34.422 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:308)
20:54:34.423 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:114)
20:54:34.424 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheFactory.java:185)
20:54:34.425 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:57)
20:54:34.426 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository.getDependency(CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository.java:44)
20:54:34.428 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleVersionRepository.getDependency(CachingModuleVersionRepository.java:90)
20:54:34.429 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.CachedRepository.getDependency(CachedRepository.java:55)
20:54:34.430 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain$RepositoryResolveState.resolve(UserResolverChain.java:184)
20:54:34.431 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain.findLatestModule(UserResolverChain.java:98)
20:54:34.433 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain.findLatestModule(UserResolverChain.java:81)
20:54:34.434 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain.resolve(UserResolverChain.java:56)
20:54:34.435 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 61 more
20:54:34.436 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

Comment: You might want to try running gradle from the command line with the "--info" option (http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html).  This won't fix the problem but it might give you something more to go on.

Comment: Are there any network or proxy problems? Have things worked okay in the past? The most likely explanation I can think of is it's having trouble downloading the Android Gradle plugin, though I'm a little surprised it wouldn't be giving you network errors when you try to build.

Comment: @ScottBarta I don't use a proxy (I do use a VPN connection - but not using it doesn't solve the problem). Up until now I always have imported projects without using gradle. But now I want to start a new project in android studio, hence I have to use gradle.

Comment: @AndroidGuy thanks the --debug gave me more info. Maybe it looks for a deprecated method? because the latest version of SLF4J is 1.7.6 and this one take the parameters: Marker,String,int,String,Object[],Throwable while the code looks for a log method with the arguments: Marker,String,String,Object[],Throwable. I am not sure if this makes sense...

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the problem here has to do with your Gradle version. The first thing I would recommend is to add a wrapper task to your build file like this:

```ruby
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

This tells the Gradle tooling that you want to use a specific version of the wrapper. After you add this task, make sure that you execute it by running the task. In the console, and from the directory where your build.gradle file is located, run this:

```
gradlew wrapper
```

It is important that you actually run the wrapper task, since just updating the value in the gradle-wrapper.properties file will not actually download your distribution. You can check which distributions have been downloaded by looking in `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists` or in `C:\Users\yourusername\.gradle\wrapper\dists`.

Finally, **the last time I checked, Android Studio didn't support Gradle 1.11 yet**. Try bumping the gradle version in the wrapper task above down to 1.9 and running the wrapper task again.

Comment: I changed to gradle 1.9. in the gradle dists folder i have "gradle-1.9-all". But when I am in my /Users/Vincent/Documents/Git/MyApplication2 folder where the gradle.build is, the command gradlew is not found.

Comment: That means that the wrapper was never generated the first time. I had assumed that Android Studio did this by default, but I must be mistaken. To generate it for the first time, you can run something like this: `C:\Users\Vincent\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.9-all\{some sort of hash}\gradle-1.9\bin\gradle.bat wrapper`. Essentially, you want to run the wrapper task using the existing gradle distribution. Doing so should generate the gradlew file, which you can use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like broken slf4j-api JAR in your Gradle installation or maybe you are adding an incompatible version of SLF4J to a classpath somewhere.